# Bind a List of Objects to Chart

Tags: c#, list, data-binding, charts

I have a list of objects:

```
List<MyClass> MyList = new List<MyClass>();
```

the MyClass contains Properties Dtm and LastPrice that are updated real-time

```
public class MyClass
{
    int dtm;
    double lastPrice = 0;

    public int Dtm
    {
        get { return dtm; }
        set { dtm = value; }
    }

    public double LastPrice
    {
        get { return lastPrice; }
        set { lastPrice = value; }
    }

}
```

I want now a chart lined to the list that updates automatically each time the properties change. Any idea on how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: You could use `BindingList<T>` for WinForms or `ObservableCollection<T>` for WPF instead of `List<T>`.

Comment: can you be more specific? or give an example?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly! Also [see here at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd456766%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

For an overview of [Binding Data to Series (Chart Controls) see here!](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd456766%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

The easiest way to bind your `List<T>` to a `Chart` is simply to set the List as `DataSource` and to set the X- and Y-Value members of a Series S1:

```
chart1.DataSource = MyList;
S1.XValueMember = "Dtm";
S1.YValueMembers = "LastPrice";
```

As for updating the chart you use the DataBind method:

```
chart1.DataBind();
```

Now you have two options:

Either you know **when** the values change; then you can simply add the call after the changes.

But maybe you don't know just when those changes occur or there are many actors that all may change the list.

For this you can add the `DataBind` call right into the **setter** of the relevant property:

```
public class MyClass
{
    int dtm;
    double lastPrice = 0;
    public static Chart chart_ { get; set; }

    public int Dtm
    {
        get { return dtm; }
        set { dtm = value; }
    }

    public double LastPrice
    {
        get { return lastPrice; }
        set { lastPrice = value; chart_.DataBind(); }
    }

     // a constructor to make life a little easier:
    public MyClass(int dt, double lpr)
    { Dtm = dt; LastPrice = lpr; }
}
```

For this to work the List must learn about the chart to keep updated. I have added a reference to the class already. So before adding/binding points we set a chart reference:

```
MyClass.chart_ = chart1;  // set the static chart to update

// a few test data using a Random object R:
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    MyList.Add(new MyClass(R.Next(100) + 1 , R.Next(100) / 10f) );
```

The reference can be `static`, as all List elements will update the same chart.

Comment: What is S1?.......

Comment: S1 is a Chart.Series that you have to add to the Chart