# Plot bubble chart for data-bound values, including bubble size

Tags: c#, sql-server, data-binding, mschart, bubble-chart

[image: i tried the Points.AddXY method as well but it gave the chart as shown in image.]

I have a table (table name is ex1, it has 3 columns: x,y and size) in sql server.

I have connected to this table from C# and want to display the contents as a bubble chart in my application. I am able to plot values of x and y axis but cannot get the bubble sizes for y values right.

I have shared the code below. This code plots x values on the x axis correctly, but uses the value of 'size' column to plot y values.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chart4.Series["Series2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bubble;
        chart4.Series["Series2"].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
        SqlConnection con0 = new SqlConnection(
         "Data Source=4L861280\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=vis1;Integrated Security=True;");
        SqlDataAdapter ad0 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from ex1", con0);
        DataTable dt0 = new DataTable();
        ad0.Fill(dt0);
        chart4.DataSource = dt0;
        chart4.Series["Series2"].XValueMember = "x";
        chart4.Series["Series2"].YValueMembers = "y";
        chart4.Series["Series2"].YValueMembers = "size";
       }
```

Comment: I want the bubbles for y values to be sized according to values in size column.

Comment: When i use AddXY method in the code as shown in image, then the chart obtained looks strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the syntax for binding with **multiple y-values** right.

Here is an example:

```
yourSeries.Points.DataBind(yourDataSource, "x", "y,size", "");
```

The trick is to **append** the second y-value for the size with a **comma** to the first one. The **third** string is for **extra** attributes you may want to bind, like `AxisLabel`, `Tooltip`, `Label`, `LegendText`, `LegendTooltip` and `CustomPropertyName` (the name of a custom property)...

They are given as named key-value pairs like this: `"Tooltip=X,otherproperty=otherfield"`

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277545/bind-a-list-of-objects-to-chart/34309372?s=4|51.4428#34309372) is a longer discussion and here is an encouraging result:

[image]

The same rules can be applied to the syntax you used:

```
chart4.DataSource = dt0;
chart4.Series["Series2"].XValueMember  = "x";
chart4.Series["Series2"].YValueMembers = "y,size";
```

Note that this way of binding doesn't allow setting the extra attibutes. [See here for a good overview of the many ways](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456766.aspx) of binding data to a `Chart`.

Comment: Thank you so much. chart4.Series["Series2"].YValueMembers = "y,size";
worked. Really appreciate your inputs. Thanks again.